Approximate $\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} dx$ to four decimals by hand
Here is one question about approximation of a definite integral from $\textbf{Demidovich}$'s Problems in Mathematical Analysis:


Evaluate $\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} dx$ to four decimals.


$\textbf{P.S.}$ Here I assume that this question does $\textbf{not}$ allow any usage of calculators or computer softwares like MATLAB and Maple, but only allows calculations by hand. And I know that there is one post talking about this question, but the solution there given by error functon doesn't solve my problem, since it cannot be done by hand.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$
By Taylor series, we have
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} dx 
&= \int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!} dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \int x^{2n}  dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
\end{aligned}
Therefore, we have
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} dx 
&= (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1})_0^1  \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{1}{2n+1}
\end{aligned}
So we get
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} dx
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{1}{2n+1}
=
1 - \frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{10} - ... + \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{1}{2n+1} + ...
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

$\textbf{Question}$
After I represent the integral in the form of series, I don't know how to continue to get the approximated value of the integral. Can someone instruct me on how to do it? Thanks!
